# User Location getting clustered as annotation

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am trying to show user location but it doesn't work the way I want.
I use this function to cluster annotations and show how many annotations it regroups :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier , for: annotation)

        annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = "identifier"
        return annotationView
}
```

Problem is: it clusters the "My Location" annotation created by :

```
showsUserLocation = true
```

But I don't to want the user location to be displayed like a simple marker on the map, I want to keep the showUserLocation "marker".

I tried to catch it like this :

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier , for: annotation)

    if annotation.title == "My Location"{
        return nil
    }
    annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = "identifier"
    return annotationView
    }
```

But it makes the app crash.

I've seen many posts about `mapView:clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations` but I don't understand how to use it.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier , for: annotation)

    annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = "identifier"
    return annotationView
}
```